# How can I retrieve the 'scheduled time' for catchup jobs in Airflow?

Tags: airflow

When building an Airflow dag, I typically specify a simple schedule to run periodically - I expect this is the most common use.

```
dag = DAG('my_dag',
      description='this is what it does',
      schedule_interval='0 12 * * *',
      start_date=datetime(2017, 10, 1),
      catchup=False)
```

I then need to use the 'date' as a parameter in my actual process, so I just check the current date.

```
date = datetime.date.today()
# do some date-sensitive stuff
operator = MyOperator(..., params=[date, ...])
```

My understanding is that setting `catchup=True` will have Airflow schedule my dag for every schedule interval between `start_date` and now (or `end_date`); e.g. every day.

How do I get the `scheduled_date` for use within my dag instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean  execution date here, You can use Macros inside your operators, more detail can be found here: https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#macros. So airflow will respect it so you don't need to have your `date` been generated dynamically

Inside of Operator, you can call `{{ ds }}` in a str directly

Outside of Operator, for example PythonOperator, you will need `provide_context=True` first then to pass `**kwargs` as last arguments to your function then you can call `kwargs['ds']`

Comment: Perfect. In my mind `execution date` is when the task actually runs, which is always 'now', but this makes sense and works.

Comment: @Chengzhi how can we do this in DockerOperator. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608355/need-to-access-schedule-time-in-dockeroperator-in-airflow