# Need to access schedule time in DockerOperator in Airflow

Tags: python, docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Need to access schedule time in airflow's docker operator. For example

```
t1 = DockerOperator(
task_id="task",
dag=dag,
image="test-runner:1.0",
docker_url="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2376",
environment={"FROM": "{{(execution_date + macros.timedelta(hours=6,minutes=(30))).isoformat()}}"})
```

Basically, I need to populate schedule time as docker environment.

Comment: This might be connected to the fact that `environment` is not a templated field and thus the template will not work. See more on that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44855949/make-custom-airflow-macros-expand-other-macros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First macros only works if it is a template_fields. Second, you need to check which version of airflow you are using, if you are using 1.9 or below, it is likely it won't work for DockerOperator which @tobi6 mentioned in the comment, since template_fields only included command (https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py#L91)

However, 1.10 stable add environment there for DockerOperator. https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py#L103

Comment: See new answer describing how to extend templated fields

Answer (score 2):

As other poster mentioned, the DockerOperator in Airflow 1.9 is only expecting the `command` field to be templated, but it is fairly trivial to modify the templatable fields on an Operator.

```
from airflow.operators import DockerOperator
DockerOperator.template_fields = (command, environment)
```

And then you can instantiate your operator as you normally would.

Comment: So this line, you would it just add to the top of a DAG? Or is this inside a function?

Comment: global on a DAG file

Answer (score 0):

A quick update :)

The environment and command parameters of the DockerOperator can be templated.
I made an article about it: https://marclamberti.com/blog/how-to-use-dockeroperator-apache-airflow/

Also, don't hesitate to take a look at the source code to see which parameter can be templated or not: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/docker_operator.py
Have a good day